# Running the official consul docker image

Tags: curl, docker, consul

I am trying to run the official docker image by doing the following

```
docker pull consul
docker run -d --name=dev-consul -p 8500:8500 consul
```

When I try to access the consul server using curl I get an empty reply

```
   vagrant@docker:~$ curl localhost:8500/v1/catalog/nodes --verbose
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8500 (#0)
> GET /v1/catalog/nodes HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8500
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

What am I missing?

Comment: instead of mapping the port?

Comment: could be a problem with your Vagrant instance - did you try using an IP instead like 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 ? (Looks like the IPv4 address isn't using localhost.)

Comment: What shows: `docker logs dev-consul`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I start consul with:

```
docker run  -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp --name=consul consul:v0.6.4 agent -server -bootstrap -ui -client=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thats right,, binding it to 0.0.0.0 made the server responsive

Comment: Hi Slawomir, your answer would be even better if you went through the parameters you use (where they're different from user_mda's original setup) and explain what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp --name=my-consul consul agent -server -ui -node=server-1 -bootstrap-expect=1 -client=0.0.0.0
```

If this command doesn't work, replace the code with this one. `-client="0.0.0.0"` (argument in double quotation marks)

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp --name=my-consul consul agent -server -ui -node=server-1 -bootstrap-expect=1 -client="0.0.0.0"
```